# inet_ntoa() and Windows User Permissions

Tags: c++, c, winsock

Is it possible to still use inet_ntoa() and not worry about Windows User Permissions? Do I need to put a try/catch block around inet_ntoa() to catch any possible problems if User Permissions prevent me from getting the IP address of an interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`inet_ntoa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564%28VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't raise exceptions. It returns `NULL` in case of an error.

It's hard to see how user permissions could come into this function since it is just an integer to string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation for [`inet_ntoa`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> If no error occurs, **inet_ntoa** returns
>   a character pointer to a static buffer
>   containing the text address in
>   standard ".'' notation. Otherwise, it
>   returns NULL.

On Windows Vista and later, the [RtlIpv4AddressToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function can be used to convert an IPv4 address represented as an IN_ADDR structure to a string representation of an IPv4 address in Internet standard dotted-decimal notation.

Comment: RtlIpv4AddressToString has the advantage that you don't need to deal with Winsock initialisation/finalisation, but the fact that it doesn't run on XP makes it less attractive.

Comment: @David:although its a simple string conversion but probably(maybe) the vista UAC has something to do with this..else why the need for a separate function with same functionality..

Comment: UAC has nothing to do with any of this. You can run through inet_ntoa under a debugger and see for yourself.